# django / ajax form submit gets 405 error but works?

Tags: python, django, ajax

What i want to do is adding photo in user album.
I have gallery.html (template of ListView).
It shows every photo in photo model.
Each photo has button for adding photo to user album.
click button -> shows form in modal -> select album -> submit
then photo is added to album, with no refresh.
It  works... harf ;( photo is added to the album. it's nice.
But i get 405 error page. what am i missing??

my code:
form in gallery.html

```
<form class='addphotoform' method="POST" id='addphotoform'>
      {% csrf_token %}
       select album.<br>
       <select class="form-select" id='album_pk' name='album_pk' aria-label="Default select example">
           {% for album in user.albums.all %}
                <option value='{{album.pk}}'>{{album.album_name}}</option>
           {% endfor%}
       </select>
       <input type="hidden" name="photo_id" id="photo_id" value="{{photo.id}}"/>  
       <button type="button submit" class="btn btn-danger">add</button>                    
</form>
```

ajax

```
$('#addphotoform').on('submit', function(event){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "{% url 'album:add_photo' %}",
      data: { csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
              photo_id : $('#photo_id').val(),
              album_pk : $('#album_pk').val()
            },

      success: function () {
        console.log('added');
      },
      error: function () {
        console.log('failed');  
      },
    });
  })
```

album/view.py

```
@login_required
def add_photo(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        photo_pk = request.POST.get('photo_id')
        album_pk = request.POST.get('album_pk')

        photo = get_object_or_404(Photo, pk=photo_pk)
        album = get_object_or_404(UserAlbum, pk=album_pk)
        
       
        album.album_photos.add(photo)
        return HttpResponse('add done')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('wrong approach')
```

gallery/view.py

```
class GalleryView(ListView):
    model = Photo
    template_name = 'gallery.html'
    context_object_name = 'photos'
    ordering = ('-date_posted')
```

album/url.py

```
 app_name = 'album'

urlpatterns = [
    path('useralbum/<str:username>/<int:pk>/', views.AlbumDetailView.as_view(), name='album'),
    path('useralbum/<str:username>/', views.UserAlbumListView.as_view(), name='user_album_list'),
    path('useralbum/<str:username>/create/', views.craete_album, name='create_album'),
    path('<int:pk>/delete', views.delete_album, name='delete_album'),
    path('<int:pk>/rename', views.rename_album, name='rename_album'),
    path('<int:pk>/del_photo', views.del_photo, name='del_photo'),
    path('add_photo', views.add_photo, name='add_photo'),

]
```

Comment: Hi, your form gets submit not ajax .Use `event.preventDefault()` inside your event handler .

Comment: @Swati Thanks!!!!  it's simple TT.  i need to study js.